# Is or was a great movie

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I went to see the movie Black Panther this morning. At night, my friend asked me about the movie. Should I say "The movie was great." or "The movie is great."?

Comment: It's not exactly the same as *I told him my name was Unni,* but the same general principle applies that the choice of tense depends on the temporal perspective of the speaker (time of speaking, or *time being spoken **of***).

Comment: So if i say movie was great, does it mean the movie is not great now? :( @fumblefingers

Comment: Not at all! You could in theory contrive a context like *When I saw the movie 40 years ago it was great. But times have changed, and everyone today agrees it's an absolutely appalling piece of racist claptrap.* But mostly we assume a good movie is, was, and always will be a good movie, so it doesn't matter if you give your opinion of it relative to what you thought *when you saw it*, or *what you think "now".*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use either. In practice, you would probably match the tense of the question.

> Friend: Did you enjoy yourself last night?
>   You: Yes, I saw *Black Panther*, and it was great.
>
> Friend: What do you think about *Black Panther*
>   You: It's a great movie.

If you are talking about the movie say "It is great". If you are talking about your night out say "It was great".

Comment: Yes, although I'd say rather match the tense to what you've got in mind: If you elect to give your opinion of the movie say "It is great". If you choose to 
 comment about your night out say "It was great".